# How do I fix the "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400"?

Tags: python, docker, nginx, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I'm using **Nginx + Gunicorn + Flask_SocketIo + Docker**.

I am running a Nginx container and a python/alpine container on one EC2 instance.

I using flask_SocketIo to send information to the client page every 5 seconds without page reload.

My application is up and running but the Socket is not connecting. So the error I'm seeing on the client side is: **Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400**

The message im getting from Nginx on the server side is:

```
**69.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [20/Dec/2020:21:06:54 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 23 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.x.xxxx.xx Safari/537.36" "-"**
```

**What my application does is:**

1. client visits http : // domain.com/project ->
2. socket connection is made which posts on the server "connected" ->
3. upon button click ->
4. server sends information continuously which is posted on the HTML page

**What I've tried:**

1. Switching from uWSGI to Gunciorn server
2. Adjusting my Nginx code for socket.io (multiple configurations)

**What works:**

1. My python scripts
2. The webpage loads when domain name is entered
3. While testing locally without Nginx, my code seems to work great.

**This is my Nginx Config:**

```html
upstream nameOfApp {
    server app:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.xxx.xxx.xx;
    server_name www.domain;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://nameOfApp;
        }
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://nameOfApp;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
    }
```

**This is my docker-compose**

```html
version: "3.7"

services:

    app:
        build:
            context: ./App
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: gunicorn mainApp.run:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8080
        container_name: app
        restart: always
        environment:
            - APP_NAME=CordLte
        expose:
            - 8080
    nginx:
        build: ./Nginx
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '80:80'
        depends_on:
            - app
```

Good thing to note is that I've **turned off polling** on the client side.

```
var socket = io({transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
```

**Update for Miguel's recommendation:**

I turned on **socket.io logger**.

```
app      | 627211f5e8984f13a467f051bc560a29: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0

app      | 627211f5e8984f13a467f051bc560a29: Received request to upgrade to websocket

nginx    | 69.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [21/Dec/2020:11:41:44 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 23 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.x.xxxx.xx Safari/537.36" "-"

app      | 129d66e4d815482cb0251c913e6cb004: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '129d66e4d815482cb0251c913e6cb004', 'upgrades': [], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}

app      | 129d66e4d815482cb0251c913e6cb004: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0

app      | 129d66e4d815482cb0251c913e6cb004: Received request to upgrade to websocket

nginx    | 69.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [21/Dec/2020:11:41:50 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 23 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.x.xxxx.xx Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Here's the result for logger upon button click:

```
app      | 1c0df226c9b14e8c8da8afe9bd1601c7: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["message",{"data":["678",0]}]

app      | 7bda92d2ea9a41c5abd22f4576d6a075: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["message",{"data":["678",0]}]

app      | 1c0df226c9b14e8c8da8afe9bd1601c7: Client is gone, closing socket

app      | 1c0df226c9b14e8c8da8afe9bd1601c7: Client is gone, closing socket

app      | 7bda92d2ea9a41c5abd22f4576d6a075: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["message",{"data":["680",0]}]
```

Let me know if there's anything else I can clarify

Comment: Probably a cross-origin problem. See the troubleshooting section of the Flask-SocketIO docs to learn how to enable Socket.IO logging. The logs will give you the exact reason for the 400 error.

Comment: @Miguel thank you for advice. I've updated my post with the logger information. Currently working on trying cross-origin. My understanding is cross-origin needs to be enabled for my blueprints.

Comment: @Miguel I used Flask_Cors and applied it to the entire project. I hope thats right, but there's been no change. Simple usage section of: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Flask-CORS is for Flask, it knows nothing of Socket.IO. There are options you can pass to your SocketIO() class to configure CORS for Socket.IO, check out the documentation: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cross-origin-controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Days later...I figured out my problem.

I needed to add the `-k gevent` on the docker-compose command. I needed to add gevent to handle my event loop. Gunicorn uses a synchronous worker class to serve requests, but it can be configured to use gevent.